# using CipherOutputStream in Java, encrypted file ends up corrupted

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am doing my bachelor thesis on the topic of cryptography and its costs.

A part of that is to compare different crypto Algorithms and Cipher Modes in terms of Runtime and Resource cost.
For that I wrote a small tool that should work in four steps:

1. Read Input File
2. Encrypt the Input File and write it to a new file.
3. Read and decrypt the just written encrypted file.
4. Write another copy of the decrypted file onto file system.
5. Compare initial input file and decrypted file to see if they are equal.

It works just fine with a small .txt input File. But for some reason it doesn’t work with any other kind of file. If I take an Image as input File, the first few pixels are good, the rest ends up corrupted.
So as far as I understand the problem should be somehow when I initialize the Cipher or when I use the Streams. 
I also tried to out comment the lines encrypting and decrypting and it also works then in just making plain copies of the input file which are identical.

Any suggestions are welcome, I will try to test them out asap and report back what results showed up.
I do apologies for the “Hungarian notations”. The p is just use for public and the l for local. It is the way we do it in our company.

So here is my class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;


public class AES_Cipher_Test {


    public String pLocalRef = "E:\\Test.txt";
    public String pLocalRefOutput = "E:\\Test-crypted.txt";
    public String pLocalCopyOutput = "E:\\Test-Neu.txt";
    public Key pKeyAES = null;
    public int pBitKey = 128;
    public Cipher pCipher;  
    public FileOutputStream pFos;
    public FileInputStream pFis;
    public CipherOutputStream pCos;
    public CipherInputStream pCis;
    public File pInputFile = new File(this.pLocalRef);
    public File pOutputFile = new File(this.pLocalRefOutput);
    public File pGeneratedFile = new File(this.pLocalCopyOutput);

    public AES_Cipher_Test() {
        crypt_decrypt_write_File();
    }

    public void crypt_decrypt_write_File() {
        byte[] lLoadedFile = null;
        byte[] lGeneratedFileByte = null;
        try {

            // generate new random AES Key
            KeyGenerator lKeygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            lKeygen.init(this.pBitKey);
            this.pKeyAES = lKeygen.generateKey();


            // read input File
            this.pFis = new FileInputStream(this.pInputFile);
            FileInputStream tempStream = new FileInputStream(this.pInputFile);
            int count = 0;
            while (tempStream.read() != -1){
                count ++;
            }
            lLoadedFile = new byte[count]; // new byte[this.pFis.available()]
            this.pFis.read(lLoadedFile);
            System.err.println("lLoadedFile.legth  " + lLoadedFile.length);
            this.pFis.close();

            //init Cipher with AES Encrypt Mode CFB8 oder CTR
            this.pCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/PKCS5Padding");
            this.pCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.pKeyAES);


            // build cipher stream from FileOutputStream
            this.pFos = new FileOutputStream(this.pOutputFile);
            this.pCos = new CipherOutputStream(this.pFos, this.pCipher);

            //write encrypted Data to stream
            this.pCos.write(lLoadedFile);
            this.pCos.close();
            this.pFos.close();

            // init Cipher for decrypt Mode
            this.pCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.pKeyAES, new IvParameterSpec(this.pCipher.getIV()));


            // read just written localFile and decrypt
            this.pFis = new FileInputStream(this.pOutputFile);
            tempStream = new FileInputStream(this.pOutputFile);
            count = 0;
            while (tempStream.read() != -1){
                count ++;
            }
            byte[] lBytes = new byte[count];// new byte[this.pFis.available()]
            this.pCis = new CipherInputStream(this.pFis, this.pCipher);
            int lBytesRead = this.pCis.read(lBytes);
            while (lBytesRead > -1) {
                lBytesRead = this.pCis.read(lBytes);
            }
            this.pCis.close();
            this.pFis.close();
            System.err.println("lBytes.length " + lBytes.length);

            // write new not crypted File to see if procedure works
            this.pFos = new FileOutputStream(this.pLocalCopyOutput);
            this.pFos.write(lBytes);
            this.pFos.close();


            //compare Input File and Output File
            this.pFis = new FileInputStream(this.pGeneratedFile);
            tempStream = new FileInputStream(this.pGeneratedFile);
            count = 0;
            while (tempStream.read() != -1){
                count ++;
            }
            lGeneratedFileByte = new byte[count]; // new byte[this.pFis.available()]
            int i = this.pFis.read(lGeneratedFileByte);
            this.pFis.close();

            System.err.println("lGeneratedFileByte.length " + i);
            System.err.println("Test if initial File and new File are identical = " + Arrays.equals(lGeneratedFileByte, lLoadedFile));


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("FILE_DOES_NOT_EXIST", e);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.err.println("Start AES_Cipher_Test");
        long start = new Date().getTime();
        new AES_Cipher_Test();
        long runningTime = new Date().getTime() - start;
        System.err.println("End AES_Cipher_Test");
        System.err.println("Runtime: " + runningTime);

    }
}
```

Comment: You should NEVER use Hungarian notation in Java.  It is completely unnecessary.  The type of a Java identifier can be determined by reading its declaration.  Java has a Style Guide ... and you should follow it if you want other people to read your code.

Comment: Your edit to the loop `while (lBytesRead <= 0)` makes even less sense than the original. `read()` can only return zero if you provide a zero length buffer, or -1 at end of stream. In neither case does it make any sense to loop, and neither case caters for the case when the `read()` doesn't fill the buffer. Your statement "Buffer size and read/write don't seem to be the problem as for not crypting just copying files it works fine" is a *non sequitur.* If you're not going to take the slightest notice of the answers you get here, I fail to see the point of posting at all.

Comment: @StephenC Sorry for the notations but I am required to use them, company standard...

Comment: @jonny - Really?  What a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

Usual series of mistakes.

- `read()` isn't specified to fill the buffer. It is only specified to transfer at least one byte, or else return -1 indicating end of stream. You have to loop:

  ```
  while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
  {
      out.write(buffer, 0, count);
  }
  ```

Your existing loop `while (!(lBytesRead < lBytes.length))` is basically nonsense.

- `available()` explicitly is not the total number of bytes in the stream, and any usage of it to allocate a buffer of such a size is explicitly stated in the Javadoc to be incorrect. Again, you have to loop, see above. There are few if any uses of `available(),` and this isn't one of them.

Comment: When commenting out the two lines that encrypt and decrypt the File, I get a plain copy which is not corrupted, forgot to mention that part...

Comment: Which 'two lines' would they be exactly? It seems to me it's more than that. In any case it would be more interesting to report what happens when you make the corrections above. They're not optional: they are mandatory.

Comment: taking out the line "this.pCos = new CipherOutputStream(this.pFos, this.pCipher);" and "this.pCis = new CipherInputStream(this.pFis, this.pCipher);" and of cause editing it so FileInputStream/FileOutputStream read and write and it just makes copys of the file. Has no problem with read() and available()

Comment: @user3497703 You're missing the point. I don't care. *Fix your code,* as suggested here and then tell us what happens if you still have a problem.

Comment: edited (hopefully) as suggested, problem stays the same.

Comment: Nothing even slightly resembling what was suggested. I told you that you have to loop, and I even gave you the copy loop. It doesn't appear anywhere in your code. Instead you have just inserted more rubbish of your own devising. This is pointless.

Comment: I do loop for every read. The buffer size is not taken from available anymore but calculated in a loop for its own. So what is pointless?

Comment: Sorry for wasting anyones time with this question. Figured out how to solve the problem. Thanks anyway